# Замена спецсимволов в строке

Tags: c#, xaml

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос такой - можно ли отменить замену угловых скобок на `&lt;` и `&gt;` при обертывании строки в XML в С#?

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=84)] 
public stringAttributeJAXBElement extendedData { 
        get { return this.extendedDataField; } 
       set { this.extendedDataField = value; } 
    }
```

Comment: наверняка можно, покажите что вы делаете, и вам скажут как

Comment: А как Вы потом этот XML читать (парсить) будете? Как узнать где тэг, а где тест?

Comment: @megacoder, похоже, у него есть какое-то поле, для которого имеется xml в строке. Вот он и хочет в xml записать шмоток xml'я как есть, т. е. без дополнительного экранирования.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте включить в сериализуемую объектную модель `XmlElement` или массив `XmlNode`. Тогда часть формируемого xml будет произвольным xml без CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря по тому, что и как вы делаете. Если вы, например, пишете строку XML в файл, используя XmlWriter, то можно оставлять скобки, вызывая метод [XmlWriter.WriteRaw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0755ytay.aspx) (переопределив его предварительно).

Comment: я принимаю с одной стороны блок CDATA, как строку, оборачиваю его в XML, как содержание узла. заием отправляю другому узлу для дальнейшей обработки. воткнул пример обертывания.